# MySQL get value from another table in query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is probably really easy to do.

I have a table `dates` and a table `inscriptions`. `dates` has 2 columns (`start` and `end`) which are `datetime`, and ALWAYS has one row. `inscriptions` has 2 rows that I want to use (`name` and `time`).
`time` is a `TIMESTAMP`.

What I want to do, is select everything where `name` is equal to something, and `time` is between `start` and `end` from table `dates`. I looked up before posting this, and someone suggested using inner joins, but I have no idea how to use them.

Thanks.

Comment: You use `INNER JOIN` if there is a common field but it looks like this one has none or at least you want your `time` to be in the range of `start` and `end`.

Comment: What is the relation between `dates` and `inscriptions`?

Comment: @Vimsha There is no "relationship". `dates` always only has one row, with the start/end dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily achieved using (as your thought) an `INNER JOIN` to the `dates` table:

```
SELECT  i.`name`,
        i.`time`
  FROM  `inscriptions` i
    INNER JOIN `dates` d ON i.`time` BETWEEN d.`start` AND d.`end`
  WHERE i.`name` = '<some criteria>'
```

Effectively, joining the rows where `inscriptions.time` falls between the `start` and `end` date from `dates`.

Answer (score 2):

something like that

```
SELECT *
FROM `inscriptions` AS i
JOIN `dates` AS d ON i.`time` >= d.`start` and i.`time` <= d.`end`
WHERE i.`name` = 'something'
```